# Term to describe the different means used to make purchases

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word/term to describe the group of different means used to purchase something:

- Cash
- Debit/credit card
- Voucher card
- Paypal account
- Check
- Bank transfer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Payment Method**

From the Business Dictionary,

The way that a buyer chooses to compensate the seller of a good or service that is also acceptable to the seller

Source: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/payment-method.html